# Month Filtration pandas dataframe Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy, date

The code below filters out the dates to get the first of each month. However for some reason it does not include the first month of each year, for example it disregards the date `'2020-01-01 00:00:00'` and goes straight to `'2020-02-01 00:00:00'`. How would i be able to fix this?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame

date_list = ['2019-09-01 00:00:00', '2019-10-01 00:00:00', '2019-11-01 00:00:00', '2019-11-05 00:00:00',
 '2019-12-01 00:00:00', '2020-01-04 00:00:00', '2020-01-12 00:00:00','2020-01-01 00:00:00', '2020-02-01 00:00:00', 
 '2020-03-01 00:00:00', '2020-04-01 00:00:00','2020-04-02 00:00:00', '2020-05-01 00:00:00', '2020-05-20 00:00:00',
 '2020-06-01 00:00:00', '2020-07-01 00:00:00','2020-07-03 00:00:00','2020-07-07 00:00:00', '2020-08-01 00:00:00',
 '2020-09-01 00:00:00','2020-10-01 00:00:00', '2020-11-01 00:00:00', '2020-11-04 00:00:00','2020-11-06 00:00:00',
 '2020-08-05 00:00:00','2020-12-01 00:00:00','2021-01-01 00:00:00','2021-02-01 00:00:00', '2021-03-01 00:00:00', 
 '2021-04-01 00:00:00']

data = DataFrame (date_list,columns=['Data'])
datetime = pd.to_datetime(data['Data'])

monthly_changes = data.loc[np.where(datetime.dt.month.diff().gt(0))].index.tolist()
```

Output:

```
['2019-10-01 00:00:00' '2019-11-01 00:00:00' '2019-12-01 00:00:00'
 '2020-02-01 00:00:00' '2020-03-01 00:00:00' '2020-04-01 00:00:00'
 '2020-05-01 00:00:00' '2020-06-01 00:00:00' '2020-07-01 00:00:00'
 '2020-08-01 00:00:00' '2020-09-01 00:00:00' '2020-10-01 00:00:00'
 '2020-11-01 00:00:00' '2020-12-01 00:00:00' '2021-02-01 00:00:00'
 '2021-03-01 00:00:00' '2021-04-01 00:00:00']
```

Expected Output

```
'2019-09-01 00:00:00', '2019-10-01 00:00:00', '2019-11-01 00:00:00',
 '2019-12-01 00:00:00', '2020-01-01 00:00:00', '2020-02-01 00:00:00', 
 '2020-03-01 00:00:00', '2020-04-01 00:00:00', '2020-05-01 00:00:00', 
 '2020-06-01 00:00:00', '2020-07-01 00:00:00', '2020-08-01 00:00:00',
 '2020-09-01 00:00:00','2020-10-01 00:00:00', '2020-11-01 00:00:00', 
 '2020-12-01 00:00:00','2021-01-01 00:00:00','2021-02-01 00:00:00', '2021-03-01 00:00:00', 
 '2021-04-01 00:00:00'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seem like it would be easier to just check that the [`day`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.day.html) was `1` (the first):

```
monthly_changes = data.loc[datetime.dt.day == 1, 'Data'].tolist()
```

`monthly_changes`:

```
['2019-09-01 00:00:00', '2019-10-01 00:00:00', '2019-11-01 00:00:00',
 '2019-12-01 00:00:00', '2020-01-01 00:00:00', '2020-02-01 00:00:00',
 '2020-03-01 00:00:00', '2020-04-01 00:00:00', '2020-05-01 00:00:00',
 '2020-06-01 00:00:00', '2020-07-01 00:00:00', '2020-08-01 00:00:00',
 '2020-09-01 00:00:00', '2020-10-01 00:00:00', '2020-11-01 00:00:00',
 '2020-12-01 00:00:00', '2021-01-01 00:00:00', '2021-02-01 00:00:00',
 '2021-03-01 00:00:00', '2021-04-01 00:00:00']
```

---

Edit: based on the comments, test if the time is also `00:00:00`:

```
from datetime import time

monthly_changes = data.loc[
    datetime.dt.day == 1 &
    datetime.dt.time.eq(time(hour=0, minute=0, second=0)),
    'Data'
].tolist()
```

`monthly_changes`:

```
['2019-09-01 00:00:00', '2019-10-01 00:00:00', '2019-11-01 00:00:00',
 '2019-12-01 00:00:00', '2020-01-01 00:00:00', '2020-02-01 00:00:00',
 '2020-03-01 00:00:00', '2020-04-01 00:00:00', '2020-05-01 00:00:00',
 '2020-06-01 00:00:00', '2020-07-01 00:00:00', '2020-08-01 00:00:00',
 '2020-09-01 00:00:00', '2020-10-01 00:00:00', '2020-11-01 00:00:00',
 '2020-12-01 00:00:00', '2021-01-01 00:00:00', '2021-02-01 00:00:00',
 '2021-03-01 00:00:00', '2021-04-01 00:00:00']
```

---

Why does the above not work?

Check out the intermediate steps:

```
datetime = pd.to_datetime(data['Data'])
data['month'] = datetime.dt.month
data['diff'] = datetime.dt.month.diff()
```

```
                   Data  month  diff
0   2019-09-01 00:00:00      9   NaN
1   2019-10-01 00:00:00     10   1.0
2   2019-11-01 00:00:00     11   1.0
3   2019-11-05 00:00:00     11   0.0
4   2019-12-01 00:00:00     12   1.0
5   2020-01-04 00:00:00      1 -11.0  # 1 - 12 !> 0
```

Comment: I have 1 minute data that goes like `'2019-09-01 00:00:00', '2019-10-01 00:01:00'`I tried to do `month_changes = data1.loc[datetime.dt.day == 1 and datetime.dt.minute == 0, 'Date'].index.tolist()` but that doesnt work. Since within the one minute data there will be 1440 values per month i have to filter out by the minute as well.

Comment: You want `&` not `and`. Also it's probably better to test that it's "00:00:00" and not just minute "0" since that would match "01:00:00" as well. Check out the edits @tonyselcuk

Comment: Also I don't know if your actual dataframe differs from the one provided, but the `index` of the _provided_ dataframe is a range index. The date values are in a column called `Data`

Comment: Thank you well explained and very helpfull

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not to use datetime as name for you series because it is common to use:

```
from datetime import datetime
```

Anyway, regarding you question

```
monthly_changes = data.loc[(datetime.dt.month!=datetime.shift(1).dt.month)].index.tolist()
```

The explanation is just that shift moves the rows forward by one, and then you'll get True for the indices where the previous month is different.